# Ajax toolkit add extender is not working

Tags: ajax, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am new bee to ajax control toolkit. I am currently using `.NET framework 2.0`. I downloaded and installed ajax control extensions and I added the dll to the toolbox. Then I dragged nad dropped the `script manager` from the ajax extensions and then a `dropdownlist` control. I tried to map this dropdownlist control with ajax dropdown extender. But that option is not displayed. I addeed my screenshot here.

[image]

I referred to this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/getting-started/using-ajax-control-toolkit-controls-and-control-extenders-vb)

Any one please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be your `installation` issue. Uninstall your `ajax` and try re-installing it.

Hope this will work !!